# Can someone explain last year's reddit exploit to me?

Tags: javascript, markdown, code-injection, reddit

Last year a user managed to inject arbitrary javascript into reddit's markdown syntax. Can someone explain how this was done and how I can test whether my site is similarly vulnerable?

Comment: add your website address i will check and tell you

Comment: I think it was through double-hashing.  Wasn't there an entry on Reddit's blog that explained the issue? Reddit is blocked where I'm at so I can't check, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Blog entry on the exploit:

http://blog.reddit.com/2009/09/we-had-some-bugs-and-it-hurt-us.html

The patch that fixed it:

https://github.com/reddit/reddit/commit/1f1f0606f5b6bf14a0db55a28cfd03e1e42e3550

Comment: The link to the patch has rotten to a 403. [This](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/commit/1f1f0606f5b6bf14a0db55a28cfd03e1e42e3550) is the same changeset on their Github account.